# c++ - Tricky Method - need solution

Tags: c++, arrays, string

The array of objects tArray contains buyer names and the numshares of there purchases, each buyer can be in the array of objects more than once. I have to return in an array the names of the five largest buyers.

I attempted to run two arrays in parallel with the buyer name and there total volume in another array.

my method in general flawed as i am getting wrong results, how can I solve this problem.

Thanks

ntransactions = the number of transactions in the array

```
string* Analyser::topFiveBuyers()
{
//set size and add buyer names for comparison.
const int sSize = 5;
string *calcString = new string[sSize];
calcString[0] = tArray[0].buyerName;
calcString[1] = tArray[1].buyerName;
calcString[2] = tArray[2].buyerName;
calcString[3] = tArray[3].buyerName;
calcString[4] = tArray[4].buyerName;
int calcTotal[sSize] = {INT_MIN, INT_MIN, INT_MIN, INT_MIN, INT_MIN};

//checks transactions
for (int i = 0; i<nTransactions; i++)
{
    //compares with arrays
    for(int j =0; j<sSize; j++)
    {
        //checks if the same buyer and then increase his total
        if(tArray[i].buyerName == calcString[j])
        {
        calcTotal[j] += tArray[i].numShares;
        break;
        }
            //checks if shares is great then current total then replaces
            if(tArray[i].numShares > calcTotal[j])
            {           
            calcTotal[j] = tArray[i].numShares;
            calcString[j] = tArray[i].buyerName;
            break;
            }   
    }
}
return calcString;
}
```

Comment: Some suggestions: compile with all warnings and debugging info (e.g. with `g++ -Wall -g` on Linux). Learn how to use the debugger (`gdb` on Linux). Consider using `std::vector`.

Comment: What results are you getting? And what results do you expect?

Comment: *"I attempted to run two arrays in parallel with the buyer name and there total volume in another array."* - parallel arrays are usually a sign that you should place the linked data in a class, and make an array of that class.

Comment: This is part of my uni work and I have restrained by the programs structure so cant add classes etc - I had calculated what results i should get in terms of buyer names but I keep getting 3/5 etc - is my logic flawed in the loop is more the big thing for me, there must be a big flaw I a missing

Comment: "I keep getting 3/5 etc" - That does not explain anything. Give a concrete example of the required output and what you are getting

Comment: output should be - halifax, w buffet, saga, sippdeal, iweb                  I am getting - halfiax, saga, buffet, iweb, sippdeal

Comment: You `//checks if shares is great then current total then replaces` - don't do this, rather insert at that position and push old values down the array, losing the lowest one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're allowed to, I'd start by accumulating the values into an std::map:

```
std::map<std::string, int> totals;

for (int i=0; i<ntransactions; i++)
    totals[tarray[i].buyername] += tarray[i].numshares;
```

This will add up the total number of shares for each buyer. Then you want to copy that data to an std::vector, and get the top 5 by number of shares. For the moment, I'm going to assume your struct (with `buyername` and `numshares` as members) is named `transaction`.

```
std::vector<transaction> top5;

std::copy(totals.begin(), totals.end(), std::back_inserter(top5));

std::nth_element(top5.begin(), top5.begin()+5, top5.end(), by_shares());
```

For this to work, you'll need a comparison functor named `by_shares` that looks something like:

```
struct by_shares { 
    bool operator()(transaction const &a, transaction const &b) { 
        return b.numshares < a.numshares;
    }
};
```

Or, if you're using a compiler new enough to support it, you could use a lambda instead of an explicit functor for the comparison:

```
std::nth_element(totals.begin(), totals.end()-5, totals.end(), 
    [](transaction const &a, transaction const &b) { 
        return b.numshares < a.numshares; 
    });
```

Either way, after nth_element completes, your top 5 will be in the first 5 elements of the vector. I've reversed the normal comparison to do this, so it's basically working in descending order. Alternatively, you could use ascending order, but specify the spot 5 from the end of the collection instead of 5 from the beginning.

I should add that there are other ways to do this -- for example, a Boost bimap would do the job pretty nicely as well. Given that this sounds like homework, my guess is that a pre-packaged solution like bimap that handles virtually the entire job for you probably would't/won't be allowed (and even `std::map` *may* be prohibited for pretty much the same reason).

Answer (score 1):

As you can have several times the same buyer, you must store a counter for all buyers, not only for 5 of them as there is no way to know that a buyer you remove from the top 5 should not be part of this top 5 (as more items could be linked to this buyer later in `tArray`).

I would suggest to use a stl map with key being buyer name and value the number of items. You fill it by iterating on `tArray` and sum all items bought by the same buyer.
Then you can iterate on the map and retrieve the 5 top buyers easily as you have only one entry per buyer.

Answer (score 0):

When the outer loop start, the index `i` is zero, and the same for the inner loop. This means that the first condition checks `tArray[0].buyerName == calcString[0]` which is equal as you set it that way before the loops. This leads to `calcTotal[0]` is increased from `-2147483648` and leaving the inner loop.

I'm not certain, but this doesn't seem like something one would want.